# How can I get mySQL enum values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, enums

For Example: In my database 'shop', I use

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD first_name ENUM('Alice', 'Bob')
```

in my terminal. How can I then store the values 'Alice' and 'Bob' as an array of seperate string values in a variable?

Comment: I think the javascript part of your question is secondary. Maybe put it like "How can I get the list of possible ENUM values in MySQL" (or whatever db you are using - please add that too).
How to execute a SQL query in JS and store in an array would be a different question then.

Comment: All DB access libraries map the result of SQL queries to native types, and DB drivers tend to implement only very basic types like numbers, text, binary strings and maybe dates. If you mean MySQL, an enum is just a string from client's point of view.